# Parent component disregards child component using Router in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-router

I have the following structure in a `Router` component:

```
export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <Router forceRefresh={true}>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
        <ParentComp>
          <Route exact path="/basic" component={BasicComp} />
        </ParentCom>
        <Route exact path="/adv" component={AdvComp} />
        <Route exact path="/settings" component={SettingsComp} />
    </Router> 
 );
}
```

The parent component contains some extra elements and its child, defined in the `props.children` variable:

```
export default function ParentComp(props) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>      
      <View>
        <Text>Parent text</Text>
      </View>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
}
```

When I check the `BasicComp` screen, it looks exactly what I wanted.

However, when I navigate to the `AdvComp` screen, ***I can see the `ParentComp` in the top half, an empty placeholder for the children(?) and the `AdvComp` below the `ParentComp`***.

Why is `ParentComp` rendered in a `Route` that has nothing to do with it?

How could I prevent the rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my assumption was false.

The rendering regards each `Route` and also the `ParentComp` *that is not a `Route`*.

So it is rendered accordingly:

- it renders a `Route` for the `Main` component and renders a `ParentComp` as well because it is not a `Route`

  - on displaying, the `BasicComp` is also displayed as it is part of `ParentComp`
- when I change the screen to `AdvComp` the `ParentComp` is also rendered as it is not a `Route`

So, I had to change the hierarchy and do everything inside the corresponding `Route`:

```
<Route exact path="/">
   <Main />
</Route>
<Route exact path="/basic">
  <ParentComp>
     <BasicComp />
  </ParentComp>
</Route>
<Route exact path="/adv">
  <ParentComp>
     <AdvComp />
  </ParentComp>
</Route>
<Route exact path="/settings">
  <ParentComp>
     <SettingsComp />
  </ParentComp>
</Route>
```

Using this apporach, everything is displayed correctly.